# Javascript - define is not defined from cdn

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a project in Laravel where I am trying to work with [spid-api](http://techdocs.spid.no/sdks/javascript/) by using Javascript SDK. I am using the cdn for the api:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.spid.se/sdk/spid-sdk-2.1.0-amd.js"></script>
```

And then trying to initiate it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Add event subscribers
  SPiD.event.subscribe('SPiD.login', function(data) { console.log(data); });
  SPiD.event.subscribe('SPiD.logout', function(data) { console.log(data); });
  SPiD.event.subscribe('SPiD.sessionChange', function(data) { console.log(data); });

  //Initiate SDK
  SPiD.init({
    client_id: 'myClientId',
    server: 'https://payment.schibsted.no'
  });
  // Check session
  SPiD.hasSession();

});
```

But I get:

> spid-sdk-2.1.0-amd.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not
> defined(…)(anonymous function) @ spid-sdk-2.1.0-amd.js:1 spid.js:4
> Uncaught ReferenceError: SPiD is not defined(…)

I read here on SO, that it is caused because I am using the require.js. How can I make both work with no errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation lists a number of hosting options](http://techdocs.spid.no/sdks/js/hosting/).

You've selected the AMD option, but you aren't running the code in an AMD environment. (If you were, `define` would be defined).

Use a different one (you probably want the "regular global variable version").

> I read here on SO, that it is caused because I am using the require.js.

No. Require.JS provides an AMD environment. It isn't working because you *aren't* using Require.JS (at least, not at the point where you try to load the AMD dependant script, you might just need to rearrange your `<script>` elements so you don't try to use `define` until after you've loaded it).